# Blank screen when accessing bios on HP ProDesk 600 G2 SFF

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, hp-pavilion, hp-elitebook

I have a brand new HP ProDesk 600 G2 SFF. When I start the PC, I see nothing for a bit, and then I see Windows 10 login screen. Whenever I try to access the bios menu, the screen goes into "Power saving mode," which also happens when I turn off the PC... How can I access the bios or track what is causing this issue?

Comment: Disable hibernation in Windows, now the bios can be accessed each time you boot.

Comment: If you have an onboard video card AND a dedicated graphics card, it is possible the BIOS is shown using the onboard video card. Try connecting the monitor to the VGA port.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the system to fully shut down by **holding shift when clicking on the shutdown button**. This will tell the computer to do a **full shutdown rather than a hybrid shutdown**. You can then try to get into the bios settings as you normally would (by hitting DEL, F8 or F12).

It is possible however that the computer is configured to skip checking for a bios key press to speed up boot time. If that is the case, you can get into the bios settings by the following steps.

You can try to access the BIOS/UEFI settings by *holding shift and clicking Restart*. This will open a menu. Next click on Troubleshoot, then click on UEFI Firmware Settings. You can also get to this menu by going to Windows Settings, next Update & Security, then System Recovery and clicking under Advanced Startup on Restart Now.

Comment: HP uses ESC for the menu, F9 for boot menu and F10 for BIOS. Also, on a HP ProDesk, you cannot disable the check for bios. HP will always give you enough time to access the menu.